# Crouton playing Animation when Crouton.cancelAllCroutons(); is called

Tags: android, crouton

is there a way that the Crouton dislays the out Animation when i cancel all croutons ?

Im using an custom layout to intercept touch events when user interacts again with the touch screen:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev)
{
    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

That Layout knows nothing about the Croutons displayed. It works this way, but instead of just make them disapear i want the out animation played (crouton going up).

I had a quick look in the source and the Builder can be used to create custom animation to show toast. When i customize the Crouton to play an fade in Animation it works like expected, only the 
out animation seems to be ignored when croutons get canceled

```
    final View customMessage = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
    final Configuration croutonConfig =  new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(Configuration.DURATION_INFINITE).setInAnimation(android.R.anim.fade_in).setOutAnimation(android.R.anim.fade_out).build();
    Crouton.make(this.getActivity(),customMessage).setConfiguration(croutonConfig).show();
```

Anyone knows how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Not with `cancelAllCroutons()`, as it removes all potential current and queued Croutons immediately and without an Animation.

You can call `Crouton.hide(...)` on your Crouton in order to remove it with the provided Animation. If you have set a `LifecycleCallback` you'll get notified that the Crouton has been removed. Then you could remove all future Croutons.